# Fail to dynamic load a component with Builder.load()

Tags: javascript, nativescript

Trying to do a dynamic load with the code:

```
  var myComponentInstance = Builder.load({
    path: "~/components/my-control",
    name: "MyControl"
  });
  console.log(myComponentInstance);
  return myComponentInstance;
```

And getting an error:

**Error: [object Object] is not a valid View instance.**

Can anyone help me to load the component? Please see the link to the playground below:

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=SoGnxo&v=18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be,

```
var myComponentInstance = Builder.load({
    path: "~/components",
    name: "my-control"
  });
```

where path should be the folder, then name shall be the component.

Comment: Hi @Manoj I have got an error with your code: 
**load() is deprecated. Use Builder.load() instead**
Can you please help?

Comment: Your import statement should be `const Builder = require("tns-core-modules/ui/builder").Builder`.

Comment: thanks a lot. I definitely missed .Builder at the end of import statement.